# how to fix conflict between two ways of input (Shiny, R) (w/ UPDATE)

Tags: r, shiny

I use a widget of file uploading to accept input data. 
In server.R:

```
getData = reactive({
        inFile = input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })
```

But sometimes the user may have no data, so I want to demo with my sample data. In server.R:

```
getData = eventReactive(input$Demo,{
    read.csv('Sample.csv') 
})
```

If I only put one option in the code, they each work. When putting them together, the `eventReactive` seems to overshadow `reactive`, and file loading isn't working. Somebody know what should I do about this? Thank you!

Complete code:
server.R

```
library(shiny)

source('1_Prepare.R')
source('Clean.R')


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    getData = reactive({
        inFile = input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })

    getData = eventReactive(input$Demo,{
        read.csv('TownShort.csv') 
    })

    output$DataBefore = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( getData() )     
    })

    result = reactive({
        if(!is.null(getData())) Clean(getData())
    })

    output$DataAfter = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[1]] )
    })

    output$Aggregation = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[2]] )
    })

    output$DataBad = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[3]] )
    })

})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel(h2("Data Cleaning: Town and State")),

    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(

            fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File (two columns: Town and State)',
                      accept=c('text/csv', 
                               'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                               '.csv')
                      ),

            tags$hr(),

            actionButton('Demo', 'Demo with sample data')

        ),
        mainPanel(

            tabsetPanel(            
                tabPanel(title=h4('Data'),
                         column(5, tags$h3('Input Data'), dataTableOutput('DataBefore')),
                         column(5, tags$h3('After Clean'), dataTableOutput('DataAfter'))
                ),
                tabPanel(title=h4('Aggregation'),
                         dataTableOutput('Aggregation')
                ),
                tabPanel(title=h4('Unrecognized'),
                         dataTableOutput('DataBad')                         
                )

            )

        )
    )
))
```

---

UPDATE
I tested and found that, two input methods `getData = reactive({...})` and `getData = eventReactive()`, whichever is behind in the code, it will overshadow the one in the front.

So I think, `getData` is a variable, I was defining it twice, and of course it forgets the first definitions. Here's fixed code:

server.R

```
library(shiny)

source('1_Prepare.R')
source('Clean.R')
DemoData = read.csv('TownShort.csv')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # one way to get data
    getDemo = eventReactive(input$Demo, {DemoData
    })

    # the other way to get data
    getUpload = reactive({
        inFile = input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })

    # condition to choose data
    getData = reactive({
        if (!is.null(getUpload())) return(getUpload())
        else if (!is.null(getDemo())) return(getDemo())
    })


    output$DataBefore = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( getData() )

    })

    result = reactive({
        if(!is.null(getData())) Clean(getData())
    })

    output$DataAfter = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[1]] )

    })

    output$Aggregation = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[2]] )
    })

    output$DataBad = renderDataTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[3]] )
    })



})
```

There is still a problem: i can go back and forth between `getData()` and `getDemo()` only once. Specifically, I can use one of them, and switch to the other. And that's it. I can't change the value of `getData()` and more.

Is there a way to refresh the value of getData? Let me know please. Thanks!

Comment: How about adding your sample return to the return case of the first, so you only have one function?  So that: getData = reactive({
        inFile = input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(read.csv('Sample.csv'))
        read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    })

Comment: Thanks @MarkeD. I tried that, and it seems the computer is impatient, and it will `read.csv('Sample.csv')` before I click the file I want to upload...

Comment: Ah yes, of course it will. Perhaps you can add some logic so the user clicks on a "load" button before it will act - using actionButton ? if (is.null(inFile) & input$actionButtonId  > 0) {do it}

Comment: Ideally all the read.csv files would be loaded as global variables, then its much easier to work with them in reactive expressions, as you dont have to load the file each time.

Comment: Thanks @pops that definitely makes sense!

Comment: hi guys I fixed it! see updates in OP~